# If sequence $\frac{n!}{2^{n}}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I must determine if sequence $\frac{n!}{2^{n}}$ converges. By induction i have determined, that this sequence is increasing.

When we will explore denominator and numerator we can conclude, that both approach infinity, if n is large. Can we from this determine, that sequence diverges? Or should i provide more arguments?

Thank you.

Comment: How could it possibly converge? If $u_n=\frac{n!}{2^n}$, then $u_{n+1}=\frac{n+1}{2}u_n$.

Comment: Your approach needs to be more rigorous. The question lies in finding which value approaches infinity at a faster pace. For example, check the sequence $(n+1)/n^4$. Both approach infinity but it is convergant.

Comment: This would depend upon what you mean by 'explore denominator and numerator'. That's fairly non-specific and could or could not be sufficient to prove it.

Comment: You can find a divergent sequence $(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $a_n \leq \frac{n!}{2^n}$ by using that $\frac{n}{2} \geq 2$ for $n \geq 4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot determine from what you have, that the series converges or diverges. Look at 
$$ a_n = \frac{2^n}{2^n+1}, \qquad b_n = \frac{3^n}{2^n} $$
Both seqeunces are increasing and have diverging numerator and denominator. So you must do something else, here is a hint: 
$$ \frac{n!}{2^n} = \frac 12 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac 32 \cdots \cdot \frac n2 
  \ge \frac 12 \cdot \left(\frac 32\right)^{n-2} $$

Comment: Thank you! I got the idea:)

Answer (score 1):

Using Stirling Formula, we have $$n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n ,$$ then, the n-th term of your sequence, when $n$ is large, reads $$a(n) = \frac{n!}{2^n} \approx \sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{2e}\right)^n ,$$ whose limit doesn't exist. Therefore, the sequence cannot converge.

Answer (score 0):

We have that the series
$$
e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
converges for each $x\in\mathbb R$ and
$$
e^{2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{n!}.
$$
Hence, $2^n/n!\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ and $n!/2^n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

By ratio test we have $$|\frac{\frac{(n+1)!}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{n!}{2^n}}|=\frac{n+1}{2}$$ which is tends to infinity so the sequence is divergent.